# What kind of List<?> will automatically eliminate duplicates

Tags: java

What kind of List will automatically eliminate duplicates when they are added.

e.g. for a List if I add 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3 = the List should just contain just 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: LinkedHashSet is one implementation of the Set interface... Why do you recommend this one rather than another ?

Comment: @pgras, perhaps because the order in which elements are added is kept in tact, just as a list.

Comment: @Wolfgang, @Bart K - the problem is that LinkedHashSet is NOT a List.  It implements the Set API, and does not allow you to get, update or insert or delete elements positionally.

Comment: you can use for(element e : collection) to iterate through it in the order things were added which can be important even if direct positional access isn't available

Comment: It is correct that the LinkedHashSet is technically not a list. But it exhibits the characteristics the op asked for and it comes with the standard library. So it may be a reasonable alternative to a "real" list.

Comment: @Stephen, I know (I didn't claim it was a list). I was just guessing why the recommendation was made.

Comment: @Wolfgang - 1) LinkedHashSet does NOT exhibit the characteristics of a real List, as my previous comment explained.  2) A better idea would be to implement a real Set/List hybrid.  A wrapper for an ArrayList and a HashSet would do the job.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is not a `List`. This is answer is incorrect as it doesn't address the original question.

Answer (score 15):

A Set will automatically eliminate duplicates, but it is a Collection rather than a List.

I don't think there is a List that eliminates duplicates in the standard library.

The [Annotated Outline of the Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html) page of the Java 6 SE API documentation says that "Duplicates are generally permitted."

Comment: +1 For pointing out the difference between Sets and Lits.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to eliminate duplicates, use [Set](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 4):

Like the above poster said, there is no List with Unique handling.

Look at [List (Java Platform SE 6)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html)

> Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements. More formally, lists typically allow pairs of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and they typically allow multiple null elements if they allow null elements at all. It is not inconceivable that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them, but we expect this usage to be rare.

Comment: Rare ... and costly.  Throwing exceptions is expensive.

Comment: expensive, true. But sometimes unavoidable. many collection methods throw UnsupportedOperationException and there is no way for client code to find out that they do in advance. RuntimeExceptions are something you have to deal with in the collections framework.

Answer (score 4):

You could extend the existing `java.util.ArrayList` and encapsulate a `java.util.Set` in it. You should override all `add(...)`, `addAll(...)` and `remove` methods and first check if an element is in the encapsulated set (in the case of adding it to the list):

```
public class ListSet<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private Set<E> set;

    public ListSet() {
        set = new HashSet<E>();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E element) {
        if(set.add(element)) {
            super.add(element);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // other add and remove methods
}
```

EDIT

As @Alnitak mentioned: don't forget to sync your backing HashSet whenever an element is removed.

Comment: I like this, and it's how I would have done it.  This specifically maintains all of the semantics of a List, whilst enforcing the no duplicates constraint (albeit at the cost of some memory). p.s. don't forget to sync your backing HashSet whenever an element is removed...

Comment: I was thinking about doing something very similar, but I'm hung up on you would implement the add(index, E) implementation.  I'd imagine that if you find a duplicate of E in the data, then you fail inserting at the position.  The List<E> interface for add(index, E) returns back void, so you can't report back this failed condition.

Answer (score 3):

You want a Set maybe, e.g. HashSet(), rather than a List?  No List will eliminate duplicates, by definition Lists permit them.

Answer (score 2):

Do not, like someone suggested, implement your own List that does duplicate check and returns false if there is a duplicate at add().

Why? Because you will BREAK the List interface contract which says:

```
public boolean add(E e)
[...]
Returns:
         true (as specified by Collections.add())
```

List.add(E e) MUST return true and add the element to the list, or throw an exception. Lists are not meant to have duplicate checks, that is what Sets are for.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you can make your own class and `@Override` add method to your class.
"just see my code and practice it"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer element) {

        if (!found(element)) {
            super.add(element);
        }
        return false;

    }
    public boolean found(Integer e) {
        return equals(e);
    }
    public boolean equals(Integer e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
            if (super.get(i).equals(e))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

public class ListRemovingDuplicated {

    public static void main(String[] abd) {

        List<Integer> obj = new MyList();
        obj.add(10);
        obj.add(20);
        obj.add(10);
        obj.add(10);
        obj.add(30);
        System.out.println(obj);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension of ArrayList that rejects duplicates:

```
public class NoDupeList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2682691450003022201L;

    public NoDupeList(){
        super();
    }

    public NoDupeList(final Collection<? extends E> c){
        super(c instanceof Set<?> ? c : new LinkedHashSet<E>(c));
    }

    public NoDupeList(final int initialCapacity){
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final E e){
        return !this.contains(e) && super.add(e);
    };

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends E> c){
        final List<E> intermediate = new ArrayList<E>(c);
        intermediate.removeAll(this);
        return super.addAll(intermediate);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(final int index, final E element){
        if(!this.contains(element)){
            super.add(index, element);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public E set(final int index, final E element){
        if(this.contains(element) && !this.get(index).equals(element)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This would cause a duplicate");
        }
        return super.set(index, element);
    };

}
```

The only thing I can't deal with is the [set()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method. My solution is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if that would cause a duplicate, but perhaps one should generally let this method throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead.

Anyway, here's a test method:

```
@Test
public void testNoDupeList() throws Exception{
    final List<String> list =
        new NoDupeList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "abc"));
    assertEquals(list, Arrays.asList("abc", "def"));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi"));
    assertEquals(list, Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi"));
    try{
        list.set(2, "abc");
        fail("This should have caused an Exception");
    } catch(final Exception e){}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get an actual `List` that is sorted and has no duplicates would be to wrap it like this:

```
List<Integer> unique = 
  new ArrayList<Integer>(new TreeSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)));
```

Note that when you add to this list duplicates will *not* be eliminated though, but maybe this works for you.